# inclusion of header files -- relative to current directory or to include directories?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have the following direcory stucture:

```
src
  +-- lib1
    +-- lib1.h
  +-- lib2
   +-- lib2.h
```

Both `lib1` and `lib2` are gonna be distributed (installed). `lib2` makes use of `lib1`, so it needs some includes:

```
#include "../lib1/lib1.h" // 1
#include "lib1/lib1.h"    // 2
#include <lib1/lib1.h>    // 3
```

(1) is the straight forward way, but is very unflexible. (2) is the way I use at the moment, but the build system needs to know that `src` needs to be added to the include path. (3) seems the best for me under the *distribution* aspect because then it can be assumed that the headers reside in a standard location, but it's not too obvious for me how a build system handles that (in this case, `lib1` needs to be installed before `lib2` can be compiled).

What's the recommended way?

Comment: What do you mean by "installing" a lib?  Is this a static or dynamic library?  If it is static then simply create a nice depot structure and add these folders to your include path.

Comment: This is all implementation specific. Some systems don't even have directories!

Comment: @EdS., I mean: The header files and libs are copied somewhere (standard location, `/usr/local/{lib,include}`) so that it's possible to use them in other projects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference between `""` and `<>` forms of include is that the `""` forms first search in some places and then fallback to the same places as `<>`.  The set of additional places is implementation dependent and the only common one is the directory of the file containing the include directive. The compiler options which add to the include path usually add for the `<>` form and so those directories get searched for both form.

So the choice between the two forms is mostly a style one.  Using the `""` form for the current project and the `<>` one for system libraries is common. For things in between, made a choice and stick to it in your project.

Comment: From the point of `lib2`: There is no difference between `lib1/lib1.h` and e.g. `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` except that they are written by the same programmer and residing in sibling directories (becasue they "mostly work together", but can also be used independently by other colleagues). But in my case I'd use the first one with `""` and the other with `<>`. +1 for pointing out that the include paths always are used as a fallback and the problem is more an aesthetic one.

Answer (score 5):

I vote for version 2.

```
#include "../lib1/lib1.h" // 1
```

This assumes the tree will always stay the same. So when you change your structure, you'll need to modify this everywhere.

```
#include "lib1/lib1.h"    // 2
```

I don't see what the problem of adding src to the include path is. Actually, you don't even need to add src to the include path, you can directly add src/lib1 and just have `#include "lib1.h"`

```
#include <lib1/lib1.h>    // 3
```

This style of includes is used for system headers. You should avoid this, as most programmers are used to see `windows.h` or `string` or `vector` inside `<>`. You're also telling the compiler to first look for those headers in default directories rather than your own. I'd avoid this one.

**Side note:**

You should think about a structure like this:

```
src
  +-- lib1
    +-- lib1.h
  +-- lib2
   +-- lib2.h
include
```

where the `include` directory contains all publicly visible headers. If `lib1.h` is public, move it there. If not, the structure you currently have should be ok.

Comment: I think you're wrong with `#include "lib1.h"`, as I said, both libs should be installed and be usable by other projects. So including `lib1/lib1.h` instead of simply `lib1.h` has the advantage that it can be used in other projects without specifying other include paths than the default one. But it was not my downvote, btw :)